# use onsen ui in cordova npm package manager

Tags: cordova, npm, npm-install, onsen-ui

I have successfully installed Onsen UI in NPM in Cordova. It is updated in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "onsenui": "^2.10.10"
  },
```

but not working in the index.html file in Cordova.
How can I make it work?
How can I link in CSS & JS file in index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add reference to Style sheet and JS library in index file

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```